# Event listener fails to work on the other inputs

Tags: javascript

**No jQuery please just pure JS**

I have this script that executes a if statement that prevents a white space to be inserted in the beginning of a input it works on section-1's first input but fails to work on the other inputs in that container call section-1 so what i'm I doing

wrong here? I tried many methods but I can not figure this out I just need to find a way were I can have the script to work on all of section-1's inputs how can I do that?

Here is my code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var trigger= document.querySelectorAll('#section-1 input');

 for(var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
   trigger[i].addEventListener('input',noStartingWhiteSpace);
 }

function noStartingWhiteSpace(){
  var preventWhiteSpaceInput= document.querySelector('input').value;
  if(/^\s/.test(preventWhiteSpaceInput))
    document.querySelector("#section-1 input").value = '';
}

});
```

```css
#section-1{
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-1 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#section-2{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-2 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#section-3{
  background-color: lime;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-3 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id='section-1'>
<input type='text' placeholder='Only this one works'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
</div><!--</section-1>-->

<div id='section-2'>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
</div><!--</section-1>-->

<div id='section-3'>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
</div><!--</section-1>-->
```

Comment: Replace `document.querySelector('input')` with `this`. Your event listener is always selecting the first one found in the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `noStartingWhiteSpace`, you are reselecting the element. You should add `e` as the first argument and use `e.target`.

For example:

```
function noStartingWhiteSpace(e){
  var preventWhiteSpaceInput= e.target.value;
  if(/^\s/.test(preventWhiteSpaceInput))
    e.target.value = '';
}
```

Comment: What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts some people want to use `this` to refer to a member property, so it wouldn't work with `.bind`.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question at hand. By that argument I could say you can't rely on `event` being the first argument because people want to use `.bind()` to prepend parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your advice every one but Daniel A. White can you give an example what you mean in a code snippet? I would better understand what you mean if you don't mind. If it's possible.

Comment: Thank you Daniel A. White I prefer your answer and sh78 answer Patrick Roberts example was good too but It did not hit just section-1 his code ended up hitting all the inputs in the document which I don't want I only wanted section-1 inputs to be targeted but thank you Daniel A. White for your lesson today great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well Patrick beat me to it, but you can also do it this way without `this`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    #section-1{
      background-color: red;
      width: 350px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #section-1 input{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    #section-2{
      background-color: blue;
      width: 350px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #section-2 input{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    #section-3{
      background-color: lime;
      width: 350px;
      padding: 20px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #section-3 input{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <br>
  <div id='section-1'>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
  </div><!--</section-1>-->

  <div id='section-2'>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
  </div><!--</section-1>-->

  <div id='section-3'>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
    <br>
    <input type='text'>
  </div><!--</section-1>-->
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

      function noStartingWhiteSpace(e){
        if(/^\s/.test(e.value))
          e.value = '';
      }

      var trigger= document.querySelectorAll('#section-1 input');
      for (var i = 0, len = trigger.length; i < len; i++) {
        trigger[i].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
          noStartingWhiteSpace(e.target);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```